# how to display data from an array in a table am getting errors

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

hi all i am trying to display array of data in a table .but the main task is i need to display all users that are under one supervisor, they may/may not have attempted the test .i am using if else condition in controller but am getting error like

> Message: Undefined index: status and Message: Undefined index:
>   submittimestamp

below is my code

**controller:**

```
   if ($supervisor) {

            $users_query="SELECT u.* ,v.value  FROM usr_data u, udf_text v   WHERE u.usr_id != 6  AND u.usr_id = v.usr_id " . $supervisor_condition . " GROUP BY u.usr_id";
// echo $users_query;
            $user_records = $this->base_model->executeSelectQuery($users_query);
            $final_dataa = [];



            foreach ($user_records as $user) {

                $user=(object)$user;


        $user_test=" SELECT u.*,o.title,ta.*,tpr.workingtime, tpr.pass, tpr.tstamp, tpr.points, tpr.maxpoints, tm.minimum_level, tcr.mark_official,(tcr.reached_points/tcr.max_points)*100 as result,v.value,ta.submittimestamp,tcr.mark_official FROM usr_data u, object_data o,tst_tests tt,tst_active ta,tst_pass_result tpr, tst_result_cache tcr,udf_text v, tst_mark tm  WHERE u.usr_id != 6 AND u.usr_id=ta.user_fi AND tt.obj_fi=o.obj_id AND v.usr_id=u.usr_id AND ta.test_fi=tt.test_id AND tt.test_id = tm.test_fi  AND tcr.active_fi=ta.active_id AND tm.passed = 1 AND ta.active_id=tpr.active_fi AND tcr.active_fi=ta.active_id   AND v.field_id='2'   AND ta.user_fi = $user->usr_id  GROUP by ta.submittimestamp";


// echo $user_test;
        $tst_records=$this->base_model->executeSelectQuery($user_test);

        if (count($tst_records)) {

            foreach ($tst_records as $tst) {
                $tst=(object)$tst;

                $dta['usr_id']      = $user->usr_id;
                                    $dta['firstname']       = $user->firstname;                 
                                    $dta['matriculation']   = $user->matriculation;
                                    $dta['approve_date'] = $this->udfTextData(1, $user->usr_id);    
                                    $dta['department']  = $user->department;
                                    $dta['job_title'] = $this->udfTextData(6, $user->usr_id);
                                    $dta['submittimestamp'] = $tst->submittimestamp;
                                    $dta['test_title'] = $tst->title;
                                    $dta['division'] = $tst->value;
                                     $mark_official = $tst->mark_official;


                                        if ($mark_official == "passed" || $mark_official == "Passed" || $mark_official == "PASSED") {
                                            $result_status = '<span class="label label-primary"> Completed </span>';

                                            $completed = TRUE;
                                        } else {
                                            $result_status = '<span class="label label-danger"> Failed </span>';

                                            $failed = TRUE;
                                        }

                                        $dta['status'] = $result_status;
                                    $final_dataa[] =  $dta;
                                }
            }
            else{

                                    $dta['usr_id']      = $user->usr_id;
                                    $dta['firstname']       = $user->firstname;                 
                                    $dta['matriculation']   = $user->matriculation;
                                    $dta['approve_date'] = $this->udfTextData(1, $user->usr_id);    
                                    $dta['department']  = $user->department;
                                    $dta['job_title'] = $this->udfTextData(6, $user->usr_id);
                                     $dta['test_title'] = $user->title;

                                     $dta['division'] = $user->value;


                                    $final_dataa[] =  $dta;

            }                 

        }                       
            }
$dataa['recordss'] = $final_dataa;
$this->load->view('supervisor', $dataa);
```

I am using if else condition if users have test else not like that .below is my view code

**view:**

```
 <h3> Skill Matrix Report Process Based Training Record in LMS </h3>
                    <hr>
                    <?php   $uniq_rec = array_unique($recordss,SORT_REGULAR);


       // var_dump($uniq_rec);
$uniq_name = array_unique(array_column($recordss, 'firstname'));
$uniq_test = array_unique(array_column($recordss, 'test_title'));
?>    

                    <table class="table" id="myTable">
                        <thead>
    <tr>

           <th>Employe NO</th>
            <th>Employe Name</th>
  <th>Date Joined</th>
          <th>division</th>
           <th>department</th>
            <th>jobtitle</th>

        <?php


        foreach ($uniq_test as $row) {
        ?>
            <th><?php echo $row?></th>
        <?php
        }
        ?>


    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php
            foreach ($uniq_rec as $row) {
              $row = (object)$row;
// var_dump($row);
                          $date_joined_y = substr($row->approve_date,0,4);
                          $date_joined_m = substr($row->approve_date,4,2);
                          $date_joined_d = substr($row->approve_date,6,2);
                          $date_joined = $date_joined_d."-".$date_joined_m."-".$date_joined_y;

        ?>




            <tr>

                     <td><?php echo ucfirst($row->matriculation); ?></td>
                     <td><?php echo $row->firstname?></td>
                     <td> <?php echo ucfirst($date_joined); ?></td>
                     <td><?php echo ucfirst($row->division); ?></td>
                     <td><?php echo ucfirst($row->department); ?></td>
                     <td><?php echo ucfirst($row->job_title); ?></td>



            <?php
                foreach ($uniq_test as $uniq) {;
                    $status = "";
                    foreach ($recordss as $rec) {
                        if($uniq == $rec['test_title'] && $rec['firstname'] == $row->firstname){
                             echo "<td>".$rec['status'].$rec['submittimestamp']."</td>";
                            $status = "true";
                        }
                    }
                    if($status != "true"){
                        echo "<td></td>";
                    }
                    $status = "";
                }
            ?>
```

but the main task is i need to display all users who are attempted test or not but those users are under one Supervisor
   submittimestampbut the main task is i need to display all users who are attempted test or not but those users are under one Supervisor.i am using if else condition in controller but am getting error like

> Message: Undefined index: status and Message: Undefined index:
>   submittimestamp

Comment: The error means they cannot find the data you need. Also, where is `$dta` initialize in your script?

Comment: in else condition am getting error but the main task is i need to display all users who are attempted test or not but those users are under one Supervisor.i am using if else condition in controller but am getting error like 
    Message: Undefined index: status and Message: Undefined index: submittimestamp  because the else condition is for if users attempted test else not .

Comment: Because in else condition where you did not find any test records, you are not setting 'status' and 'submittimestamp'. And those tuples are being processed in the view.